# HTML page loading last content

Tags: html, iframe

I have two pages, index.html and info.html and when I open info.html via index.html I have 4 options: Option 1, Option 2, Option 3 and Option 4.

When I open Option 1 it shows a image and I close the page to show again index.html and when I choose to open info.html again it shows last content, option 1 image. And it's suposed to show the 4 options again.

How to solve that?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th,tr {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Piso</th>
    <th>Sala</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Entrada</td>
     </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><a href="test.html">Option 1</a></td>
     </tr>

      <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Option 2</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Option 3</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Option 4</td>
     </tr>



</table>

</body>
</html>


  </body>
</html>
```

Index.html loading info.html:

INFO

```
        <iframe align="center"src="INFO.html"  width="100%" height="500" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" >
        <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
                                        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>

    </article>
```

Comment: In order to help you we will need to know what JavaScript you're using and how, and how your server is delivering the content *i.e.* if it is being cached (as images often are) etc. We need more info.

Comment: Maybe I don't using much javascript, to open info.html I'm using iframe. 
Going to update main post

Comment: If you're not using JavaScript in any relevant way, please also remove the JavaScript tag.